# Using BeautifulSoup, I am getting two different results when calling the same function in two different situations

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I defined 12 functions with the objective to retrieve specific data points from reviews website.

Among the information that I am retrieving are restaurant name, rating, phone, address, and restaurant link.

Then I iterate through the list that had the restaurants links and I open it using Beautiful Soup. By doing so, I will have access to other data points that I want to retrieve, such as the name of the reviewer, his or her location, the number of reviews that he or she has made, date of the review, and the review that he or she wrote.

The first function that I am gonna use with the list of new links is called getReviewerName, which takes in two arguments (the links, and a header with a new user-agent.

The problem comes here. When the `getReviewerName` is going through the list of new links to get the names of the reviewers, I am getting `"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"`.

However, when I use the `getReviewerName` with just one single url, it works just perfectly.

## HERE IS THE CODE:

```
def getReviewerName (restaurantLink, header): 
    time.sleep(4) 
    session = requests.Session() 
    req = session.get (url, headers = header) 
    bs = BeautifulSoup (req.text, "html.parser") 
    comments = bs.find ("div", {"class":"review-list"}) 
    authorDiv = comments.find_all ("div", {"class":"media-story"}) 
    nameTag = [a.find ("li",{"user-name"}) for a in authorDiv] 
    name = [name.text for name in nameTag] 
    names = [n.replace("\n","") for n in name] 
    return names


def getRestaurantLink(bs):   
    time.sleep(4) 
    listLinks = [] 
    restGrid = bs.find_all ("ul", {"class": "lemon--ul__373c0__1_cxsundefined list__373c0__2G8oH"}) 
    for i in restGrid: 
        link = i.find_all("a", {"href": re.compile ("/biz/.*")}) 
        for l in link: 
            if "target" in l.attrs and "name" in l.attrs and "rel" in l.attrs: 
               listLinks.append (l.attrs["href"])
    restaurantLink = []           
    for link in listLinks[0::3]:
        newLink = ("https://www.yelp.com"+str(link))
        restaurantLink.append (newLink)
    return restaurantLink




def startScraping (url, header): 
    time.sleep(4) 
    session = requests.Session() 
    req = session.get (url, headers = header) 
    bs = BeautifulSoup (req.text, "html.parser")


    restaurantName = getNames(bs)
    restaurantRating = getRating (bs)
    restaurantPhone = getPhone (bs)
    restaurantAddress = getAddress (bs)
    restaurantLink = getRestaurantLink (bs)


    print (restaurantName)
    print (restaurantRating)  
    print (restaurantPhone)
    print (restaurantAddress)
    print (restaurantLink)

    for link in restaurantLink:

    # THIS IS THE FUNCTION I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH:

        reviewerName = getReviewerName (link, header)

        reviewerLocation = getReviewerLocation (link, header )
        reviewerTotalReviews = getReviewerTotalReviews(link, header )
        reviewerRating = getReviewerRating(link, header )
        reviewDate = getReviewDate(link, header)
        review = getReview (link, header)


        print (reviewerName)  
        print (reviewerLocation) 
        print (reviewerTotalReviews)      
        print (reviewerRating)
        print (reviewDate)     
        print (review)



headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;  rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"}
url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?  find_desc=&find_loc=Hunts+Point%2C+Bronx%2C+NY&ns=1"

startScraping (url, headers)



OUTPUT:

-----------------------------------------------------------------     ----------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent   call last)
<ipython-input-142-ddbec6805e6f> in <module>()
  2 url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?  find_desc=&find_loc=Hunts+Point%2C+Bronx%2C+NY&ns=1"
      3  
----> 4 startScraping (url, headers)

<ipython-input-141-2e3b65c73e53> in startScraping(url, header)
    166 
    167     for link in restaurantLink:
 --> 168         reviewerName = getReviewerName (link, header)
    169         reviewerLocation = getReviewerLocation (link,  header )
    170         reviewerTotalReviews = getReviewerTotalReviews(link, header )

 <ipython-input-141-2e3b65c73e53> in  getReviewerName(restaurantLink, header)
    70     bs = BeautifulSoup (req.text, "html.parser")
    71     comments = bs.find ("div", {"class":"review-list"})
---> 72     for comment in comments:
     73         if comment is not None:
     74             authorDiv = [comment.find ("div",     {"class":"media-story"}) for comment in comments]

 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable



# HOWEVER, WHEN I CALL THE getReviewerName (link, header) WITH  JUST ONE URL I GET THE DESIRED RESULT:

def getReviewerName (restaurantLink, header): 
    time.sleep(4) 
    session = requests.Session() 
    req = session.get (url, headers = header) 
    bs = BeautifulSoup (req.text, "html.parser") 
    comments = bs.find ("div", {"class":"review-list"})  
    authorDiv = comments.find_all ("div", {"class":"media-story"}) 
    nameTag = [a.find ("li",{"user-name"}) for a in authorDiv] 
    name = [name.text for name in nameTag] 
    names = [n.replace("\n","") for n in name] 
    return names

url = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/the-boogie-down-grind-café-bronx"
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;  rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"}
getReviewerName (url, headers)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Bumble B.',
 'Mel G.',
 'Hadassah B.',
 'Jackeline F.',
 'Annie Boom F.',
 'Elvis A.',
 'Anjel P.',
 'Tashalee C.',
 'Deepakie S.',
 'Lidia D.',
 'Mercedes C.',
 'Rachel N.',
 'Jessica M.',
 'Nirva A.',
 'Julissa A.',
 'Samantha T.',
 'Sean B.',
 'Chad J.',
 'Angel R.',
 'Riley R.']
```

Comment: I see two situations: (1) some pages don't have this element so you get `None` (2) server blocks scripts/bots and maybe you get page warning. In both situations you should display HTML or save in file and open in browser to see if you get expected data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response @furas I tried a list comprehension to say "if the value is not None, continue the process" but I am still getting the same error.  I think I might be getting a page warning. To avoid this, I am using a different user-agent, and Sessions( ). Any suggestion on what else should I use to avoid being blocked?

Comment: first check what you have in HTML. You may use different User-Agent and Session but it can block your IP or it may use other unknow method. As for error - always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: page may use random names for classes - I can't get links with your class `"lemon--..."` but if I use `{"class": lambda x:x.startswith("lemon")}` then I can get few links. Page can also use JavaScript to add elements - BS/request doesn't run JavaScript.

Comment: this is so helpful! thanks @furas